# reverting between marginnote margins and 'normal' margins

Tags: margins

How can I revert to normal margins while using marginnote s?  In other words, in some pages of my document where I won't use marginnotes, I want the margins to be normal, as though I'm not using marginnotes.

Comment: The margin should -- in my opinion -- not be affected by the margin note. Can you show an example where the margins change after inserting a note?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen : I think OP wants to have two different options for margins (and textblock width), depending on whether the particular page has marginal notes, or not. (Humble opinion: I don't think the result will be very pretty)

Comment: Yes Brent, that's what I need.  I'm writing a math manual and i'm using lots of marginnotes for diagrams, tips, etc. But when I get to the exercise pages, there's this huge margin that I wish to make narrower.

Comment: \documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[centering,marginparwidth=1.5in,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\evensidemargin 1.5in
\oddsidemargin 1.5in
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\marginnote{test test test test test test test}
\lipsum[1-2]\marginnote{test test test test test}
%%%%%%%%%% here I get the same wide margin that I had to use for marginnote, 
%%%%%%%%%% but I want to make it narrower.
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}

Comment: oops I guess I dont know how to add the file....

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible (or at least not really feasible) in TeX to change the text width at a page break, paragraphs are set in advance and broken into a series of lines, and then these lines are broken into pages. So you can not, after deciding the page break change the line width as the remainder of the paragraph has already been set.

If however you want manually break the pages with `\clearpage` or similar commands then you know that the page break does not happen mid-paragraph so it is possible to change the width.

Easiest is probably to use the `geometry` package which allows multiple page sizes to be set up.